# How to extract the text of a text node that is not inside a tag of its own using Selenium and Java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get a single line of text (e.g. standard_user). How can i do this?

```
<div id="login_credentials" class="login_credentials">
              <h4>Accepted usernames are:</h4>

              standard_user
<br>
              locked_out_user
<br>
              problem_user
<br>
              performance_glitch_user<br>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Collect all the text contained in one div, and separate them with break lines:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("login_credentials"));
String lines[] = element.getText().split("\n");
System.out.println(lines[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to read the File line by line and set a condition to get the line with *no Tag*

```
if(!line.startwith("<"){ //your code}
```

or use a library for reading html file depend on your programming language

Answer (score 0):

I would use a few lines to process the text -- it's a bit tricky with `<br>` elements and elements containing partial text:

```
// first, get all the text by locating div element
string allText = driver.findElement(By.id("login_credentials")).getText();

// then get H4 text so we can remove this string
string textToRemove = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='login_credentials']/h4")).getText();

// remove unwanted "Accepted usernames are:" text
string filteredText = allText.Replace(textToRemove, "");

// split filteredText on newline regex so we can get line items including 'standard_user'
string[] textArray = filteredText.split("\\r?\\n");

// get standard_user text by getting first item in the split array
string standardUserText = textArray[0];
```

The last 3 lines of this code can be simplified, but I wrote out this longer version of it so we can understand what is happening in each step.

`allText` variable after evaluation should be equal to `Accepted usernames are: standard_user locked_out_user problem_user performance_glitch_user`.

Once we remove the `Accepted usernames are:` text that appears in the `h4` element, `filteredText` is equal to `standard_user locked_out_user problem_user performance_glitch_user` with each item separated by a newline, either `\r` or `\n` character -- we use a regex to handle both cases..

We split `filteredText` on `\n` character so we get an array as follows:

```
[ "standard_user", "locked_out_user", "problem_user", "performance_glitch_user" ]
```

Then, we can call `textArray[0]` to get first item in list, which should be `standard_user`.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the div content and use some string manipulation with line break.

```
String text=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#login_credentials")).getText();
String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
System.out.println(lines[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The text **standard_user** is a *text node* with in the `<div>` node. So to extract the text **standard_user** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println((String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.login_credentials#login_credentials")))));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='login_credentials' and @id='login_credentials']")))).toString());
  ```